# if and elsif optimisation in Ada 95

Tags: ada

I'm working on an Ada based project that I'm not terribly familiar with, and I've just seen something that at first glance seems inefficient, but of course that all depends on what the compiler might do.

```
if Ada.Strings.Fixed.Trim
    (Source => Test_String,
     Side   => Ada.Strings.Both) =
    String_1 then
    --Do something here
elsif Ada.Strings.Fixed.Trim
    (Source => Test_String,
     Side   => Ada.Strings.Both) =
    String_2 then

    --Do something else here
end if;
```

I feel that it would be more efficient to call the Trim procedure and store the result in a String variable, then test against different Strings in each condition of the if statement, especially if there are many conditions to check (never mind that using a binary search might be even better). Of course, I may be wrong, so my question is, is there something about compile time optimisation in Ada that I do not know about, that might cause the Trim function to only be called once, and only have the result tested in each condition of the if statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think we need to worry about efficiency for this case. But the coding style that do need to be improved. To define a variable to hold the result of the Trim function is a better practice in my opinion.  The program logic is clearer and easier for maintenance.

Let's say you want to change the Trim function to another one or change the parameter passing in, you only need to change one place. Although for this case there are only two places, you still have a chance to error. If there are more cases to test, then there definitely will be missing case.

Comment: I completely agree, it's not really an efficiency issue, but a readability one. The sad fact is this project is full of poor decisions like this, this is just a simple example.

Answer (score 6):

That would be compiler-dependent, not language-dependent. Certainly, GNAT GPL 2013 calls `Trim` twice both at `-O2` and at `-O3`.

Your (and my) intuition seems to be right: do the trim once and store the result ...

```
Trimmed : constant String :=
  Ada.Strings.Fixed.Trim (Source => Test_String, Side => Ada.Strings.Both);
```

... though personally I’d write

```
Trimmed : constant String :=
  Ada.Strings.Fixed.Trim (Test_String, Side => Ada.Strings.Both);
```

on the grounds that in this case no one should need the named parameter association to clarify the programmer’s intention!

Answer (score 3):

While I have no disagreement whatsoever with your assessment or Simon's answer, it's worth bearing in mind what optimisation actually means...

If each call to "trim" takes (conservatively) 0.1ms of CPU time, and the rewrite takes 2 minutes, the breakeven point in time saved is over 1 million executions of that particular statement!

This of course ignores (a) on the positive side, the value of gaining experience, and (b) on the negative side, the fact that CPU time is nowadays less valuable than your time. And (c) the time we have spent discussing the optimisation too!

Comment: I suppose it wasn't clear in my question, but I'm really thinking "It would be more readable to do it a different way." Given that this is safety critical code, I'm having a hard time understanding how code like this got past independent code reviews, since poor readability hinders maintainability. Now I'm the poor sod that has to maintain it.

Comment: For readability, clarity and maintainability,  I absolutely agree with you - but that's not covered by the question! My preferred pattern is a constant string initialised by calling Trim - in a declare block if necessary. Ada's facility for variable length storage on the stack is one of those "minor" features that in practice goes a huge way to eliminating breeding grounds for bugs. (And it's "efficient" compared to malloc/free too!) The question is, how much permission/freedom do you have to refactor it and improve it? Which probably comes down to the cost of re-qualifying it.

Comment: True, though I did write the question in the hopes of gaining some more insight, which worked! 

I don't really have any freedom, I just have to add the features I've been told to add, which I feel makes the situation worse. There's no time in the project to do anything else.

Answer (score 3):

With respect to "compile time optimisation in Ada" , the Ada language doesn't say anything about this.  All it would say here is that the program must behave as if the function were called twice, i.e. it must produce the same results.  But if the compiler "knows" that the function would produce the exact same result the second time, it can generate code that calls it only once.  It can't do this for a function call in general, because a function could include side effects or use global variables that whose values could have changed.  In this case, since the effects of `Ada.Strings.Fixed.Trim` are defined by the language and since those effects do guarantee that the effects would be the same, a compiler could, in theory, mark this function as one for which a call with the exact same parameters could be optimized.  (A function in a `Pure` package would definitely be one where a second call could be eliminated, but unfortunately `Ada.Strings.Fixed` isn't defined by the Ada language as being `Pure`.)  To find out whether a compiler actually does this particular optimization, though, you'd have to try it and check the code.  I believe that if `Test_String` is not marked as `Volatile`, then compilers are allowed to assume that its value will be the same for each `Ada.Strings.Fixed.Trim` call (i.e. it can't be changed by another task in between the calls), but I'm not 100% sure about this.

I'd declare a constant to hold the result (like Simon), but for me this is more out of a desire to avoid duplicated code than it is out of a concern for efficiency.